# VGA red secondary screen problem

Tags: screen, tv

When I connect my VGA cable from PC to TV ICARUS IC-LED32H-B/HK all colors became black and red. Can someone help me with this problem, please? Cable is fine (tested on another screen). Thank you.

[image: here is img]

Comment: I would re-check your cable connections; that the contacts are clean & make good contact, as the only time I've had this was due to vga connection issues (usually connector not correctly on is more common than bad cable in my experience). If the cable isn't flat (because of interference with another cable or just bad fit, thus it's not on straight & some pins have poor contact - you need to fix this).

Comment: thank you for comment.. this not cause the problem. Connection between the same PC (but run on windows) to TV function perfect